# How do I capture all failed nodes from API response

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

For each request that is made a response is given. My goal is to capture all nodes that return false. At the moment I am only able to store the last response.

Here is an example of a failed response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lead_return_response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://lead.com/api/2/">
  <success>false</success>
  <message>Lead is Already in Return List</message>
</lead_return_response>
```

Here is my code block:

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def return_leads():
    with open('return_leads.csv', 'r') as csv_file:  #opens csv file as var csv_file
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)  #csv.Dictreader turns values from csv 'returns_lead.csv' and converts to key values pairs

        for data in csv_reader:  #looping through data in csv file
            url = 'https://api.com.'  #request URL for API
            params={"api_key": "#########",  #api key is only static value
                    "lead_id": data['Lead ID'],  #passing dynamic values from csv to required API parameters
                    "vertical_id": data['Vertical ID'],
                    "buyer_contract_id": data['Buyer Contract ID'],
                    "return_type": data['Return Type'],
                    "return_reason_id": data['Return Reason ID'],
                    "reject_reason_id": data['Reject Reason ID']}
            req = requests.get(url, params=params)  #request is generated for each line item in the csv file
            print(req.text) #response from API request is captured

#Print Output:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lead_return_response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://cakemarketing.com/api/2/">
  <success>false</success>
  <message>Lead is Already in Return List</message>
</lead_return_response>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lead_return_response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://cakemarketing.com/api/2/">
  <success>false</success>
  <message>Lead is Already in Return List</message>
</lead_return_response>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lead_return_response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://cakemarketing.com/api/2/">
  <success>false</success>
  <message>Lead is Already in Return List</message>
</lead_return_response>




            print(url, params) #check how params are being populated with dynamic data

#Print Output:

https://affiliates.ahs.com/api/2/track.asmx/ReturnLead {'api_key': '', 'lead_id': 'CB220BCB', 'vertical_id': '43', 'buyer_contract_id': '4', 'return_type': 'submit_for_approval', 'return_reason_id': '1', 'reject_reason_id': '0'}

https://affiliates.ahs.com/api/2/track.asmx/ReturnLead {'api_key': '', 'lead_id': 'D8E43B8D', 'vertical_id': '43', 'buyer_contract_id': '4', 'return_type': 'submit_for_approval', 'return_reason_id': '1', 'reject_reason_id': '0'}

https://affiliates.ahs.com/api/2/track.asmx/ReturnLead {'api_key': '', 'lead_id': '9B45E52E', 'vertical_id': '43', 'buyer_contract_id': '4', 'return_type': 'submit_for_approval', 'return_reason_id': '1', 'reject_reason_id': '0'}

            response = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
            print('response:', response)
            responseFalse = response.find('success').string
            responseMessage = response.find('message').string
            if responseFalse == 'false':
                captureResponse = []
                captureResponse.append(data['Lead ID'])
                captureResponse.append(responseFalse)
                captureResponse.append(responseMessage)

print('caputureResponse:', captureResponse)

#Print Output:

 ['9B45E52E', 'false', 'Lead is Already in Return List']

return_leads()
```

My goal is for captureResponse[] to contain all 3 leads that failed instead of the last one only. Can anyone correct what I am doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## init just once

Please initialize the list near top of function:

```
def return_leads():
    captureResponse = []
    with open( ...
```

Your code was initializing it waaayyy down in the function,
inside the `for` loop,
inside a test for false.

The effect was to put a very nice value #1 into the list,
then we'd set the list to `[]` followed by putting a very nice value #2 into it.
and again reset it to `[]` before value #3 went in.

## data structure

Also, three `.append()` calls is probably not quite what you want.
It would make more sense to construct a tuple, and append *that*:

```
            captureResponse.append((data['Lead ID'], responseFalse, responseMessage))
```

The tuple might be clearer when broken out on a separate line:

```
            summary = data['Lead ID'], responseFalse, responseMessage
            captureResponse.append(summary)
```

Comment: This was very helpful! I ended up using: summary = data['Lead ID'], responseFalse, responseMessage
            captureResponse.append(summary) and added my list at the top of my code. I'm still pretty new at this as you can probably tell. I really appreciate you answering in a timely manner.